# How to show all categories of custom post type with category thumbnail which is created by ACF in a loop?

Tags: wordpress, loops, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

How to show all categories of custom post type with category thumbnail which is created by ACF in a loop?

````
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3">
            <div class="c-brintons-box">
                <div class="c-brintons-img">
                    <img src="img/brintons-3.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <h3>Royal Marquis</h3>
                <a href="#"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
   'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy_slug', // enter your taxonomy slug here
   'hide_empty' => false,
) );
foreach($terms as $term) {
    $img = get_field('img_field_name', $term); // enter your img field name here
    $term_name = $term->name;

    // TODO: Your HTML code here
}
```